# Ubuntu Crash and beeps

Tags: crash

For some time my computer has been beeping three beeps together, then one and after awhile a long beep. Today ubuntu crashed. Any suggestions on what to do? I don't know if the two probelms are related.

Answer (score 2):

The beeps that you are hearing are indications from your computer that there is a hardware problem.

Here is a list of the beep codes: http://www.computerhope.com/beep.htm

Different manufactures have different codes.

I would start to diagnose this by checking the RAM first. The memory is usually what breaks.

You can test the RAM by booting a Ubuntu live DvD/USB and running a memory test.

Press any key while the live DvD/USB is starting. Then select memory test from the options that are presented. It will take a while to check the memory. If the computer crashes, or the test fails then you need to replace the memory in the computer.

If the test passes then something else in the computer is broken. I would then remove the graphics card, if there is one, and see if the computer works with it removed.